# Redhat 7 DNS Bind Failed to restart

Tags: rhel, dns, bind

I am getting Error while Restarting the Named.service in Red-hat 7
Here is my Lab Status and all the Command.

Configure DNS in REDHAT 7
DNS Name    p1.linux.com
IP address  192.168.1.1/24
N/W ID  192.168.1.0/24

```
[root@p1 Desktop]# hostname
p1.linux.com

# yum -y install bind bind-utils
```

it was successful

**Configuring BIND:**
I have Edited the Following Lines

```
[root@p1 Desktop]# vim /etc/named.conf
options {
        #listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
        #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost;192.168.1.0/24; };
        allow-transfer  { 192.168.1.1; };

zone "linux.com" IN {   
    type master;
    file "fwd.linux.com.db";
    allow-update { none; };
};  

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {  
    type master;
    file "1.168.192.db";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

**Create a zone file called fwd.linux.com.db for forward zone under /var/named directory**

```
# vi /var/named/fwd.linux.com.db

$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     p1.linux.com. root.linux.com. (
2014112511  ;Serial
3600        ;Refresh
1800        ;Retry
604800      ;Expire
86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
;Name Server Information
@      IN  NS      p1.linux.com.
;IP address of Name Server
primary IN  A       192.168.1.1
;Mail exchanger
p1.linux.com. IN  MX 10   mail.linux.com.
;A - Record HostName To Ip Address
www     IN  A       192.168.1.100
mail    IN  A       192.168.1.150
;CNAME record
ftp     IN CNAME        www.p1.linux.com.
```

**Create a zone file called 1.168.192.db for reverse zone**

```
# vi /var/named/1.168.192.db

$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     p1.linux.com. root.linux.com. (
2014112511  ;Serial
3600        ;Refresh
1800        ;Retry
604800      ;Expire
86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
;Name Server Information
@ IN  NS      p1.linux.com.
;Reverse lookup for Name Server
1        IN  PTR     p1.linux.com.
;PTR Record IP address to HostName
100      IN  PTR     www.linux.com.
150      IN  PTR     mail.linux.com.
```

**Now Problem Occur**

```
[root@p1 Desktop]# systemctl restart named.service
Job for named.service failed. See 'systemctl status named.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
[root@p1 Desktop]#
```

Here is error

```
[root@p1 Desktop]# systemctl status named.service
named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-03-11 13:25:43 IST; 1min 0s ago
  Process: 5283 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z /etc/named.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 11 13:25:43 p1.linux.com named-checkconf[5283]: _default/linux.com/IN: bad zone
Mar 11 13:25:43 p1.linux.com named-checkconf[5283]: zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2014112511
Mar 11 13:25:43 p1.linux.com named-checkconf[5283]: zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
Mar 11 13:25:43 p1.linux.com named-checkconf[5283]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
Mar 11 13:25:43 p1.linux.com named-checkconf[5283]: zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: ...erial 0
Mar 11 13:25:43 p1.linux.com named-checkconf[5283]: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Mar 11 13:25:43 p1.linux.com named-checkconf[5283]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Mar 11 13:25:43 p1.linux.com systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 11 13:25:43 p1.linux.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Mar 11 13:25:43 p1.linux.com systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@p1 Desktop]#
```

What is the Problem and How should i solve it 
can any one check it 
Thank you 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have an NS record in the `linux.com` zone with the value `p1.linux.com`, but no A record for `p1.linux.com`.

You have an A record for `primary.linux.com` with the comment *IP address of Name Server* but that's wrong, and such comments can blind you to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close up your options stanza.

```
options {
    #listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
    #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost;192.168.1.0/24; };
    allow-transfer  { 192.168.1.1; };
};  ## This right here. You're missing this.
```

As a side note... this wouldn't stop bind from starting up, but you need an A record for `p1.linux.com`. Otherwise an nslookup will not find it.